# Custom Django 1.4.5 management command not found

Tags: python, django

I am working on a legacy python application developed with Django 1.4.5 and trying to create a custom management command.

My app is called `george` and here's the folder structure (I've omitted out other irrelevant files & folder):

```
manage.py
/george
    __init__.py
    /management
        __init__.py
        /commands
            __init__.py
            what_time_is_it.py
```

And this is the content of **what_time_is_it.py**:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Displays current time'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = timezone.now().strftime('%X')
        self.stdout.write("It's now %s" % time)
```

and I made sure `george` is included in my `settings.py` under `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'george',
    ...
)
```

The app is running in a docker container, so after building and running the container, i shelled into it and ran this command:

> root@e1973c07ba61:/code# python manage.py what_time_is_it

and I get this error:

```
Unknown command: 'what_time_is_it'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? When I run `python manage.py help` I don't see my custom command listed there, as if it's not registering.

Comment: I wasn't around for 1.4 and the docs only go back to 1.7, but maybe custom management commands weren't available in 1.4?

Comment: Django 1.4.x went end-of-life four years ago. You're missing out on years of security releases. At the very least, upgrade to 1.4.22 so that you get security fixes up to August 2015. You can still see the docs on readthedocs: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.X/howto/custom-management-commands.html. The code you have posted looks ok so it's hard to offer suggestions. Are you sure that the files structure inside the container is correct?

Comment: Does `george/models.py` exist? IIRC that might be an issue for old versions of Django.

Comment: @Alasdair there is no `george/models.py` file but there is a models dir here with bunch of files: `george/models/...`

Comment: Make sure that `models/__init__.py` exists. If it does, then I would try to add some printing/logging to [`django/core/management/__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/management/__init__.py) to figure out why your command isn't being discovered.